# Converting to string NodeJS Express http response returns in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to build an angularjs program which talks to express / nodejs api and mysql database.

In login page , I am able to call the api correctly and it connects with mysql and based on right combination of user name and password , I am sending back `"password matches"` or `"failure"`.

When I am accessing that on HTML using `$scope` , I am getting `["password matches"]` and not **password matches** . I have tried `toString`, `splice`, etc but no proper result.

**Controller**

```
var passStats=[];  
passStats = LoginFactory.validateUserLoginFactory(uName, pWD)      
$scope.pwdStatus = passStats;
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory("LoginFactory", function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.validateUserLoginFactory = function (UserName, PWD) {

        $http({ method: "POST", url: 'http://localhost:3000/validateUserLogin/', data: { limit: userForm }, cache: false }).then(function (response) {        
           StatusPWD.push(response.data);         

        }, function (error) { console.log(error); });
        return StatusPWD;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

**node.js**

```
res.send('password matches');
```

**HTML**

```
<label>User Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="enteredUserName" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
<br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="enteredPWD" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
<br>
<input type="button" ng-Click="validateLogin(enteredUserName,enteredPWD)" value="Login" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-green">
<br> <br> <br>
<label>password {{ pwdStatus}}</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `StatusPWD.push` which is pushing it into an array.

the `passStats` variable is an array, where you are pushing the response.

you can simply do this to get the value if `passStats` is an array 
`$scope.pwdStatus = passStats[0]`
or you can do
`$scope.pwdStatus = passStats.join("")`

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions, none is working . I am getting an empty string in both cases, where as  $scope.pwdStatus = passStats; gives me the ["password matches"] as said before

Comment: @BCool can you change the line `$scope.pwdStatus = passStats;` to `$scope.pwdStatus = passStats.join(" ")` and check.

Comment: No its not working . Even I tried res.format ({ 'text/plain': function() {
    res.send('password matches');
   }
   });  Even though I get the string (not array ) in Factory , it does not show up in controller or HTML

Comment: try changing this line `StatusPWD.push(response.data);` to `StatusPWD = response.data;`

Comment: I think I need a proper answer..I have researched a lot . So please dont down vote my question

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem for which I posted the question. I had coded the factory and controller part wrongly. Following modification is giving me proper out put in HTML

**Factory**

```
factory.validateUserLoginFactory = function (UserName, PWD) {
    var userForm = {};       
    userForm = { user: UserName, password: PWD };       
    return $http({ method: "POST", url: 'http://localhost:3000/validateUserLogin/', data: { limit: userForm }, cache: false });       
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.pwdStatus;
   LoginFactory.validateUserLoginFactory(uName, pWD)  
  .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.data);
       $scope.pwdStatus = data.data;
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```